# Kendo React DropDownList subclass values not appearing in Form

Tags: reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I inherited a Kendo React subclass from a colleague.  The subclass name is `FormDropDownList`.

It is a basic combination of a `Label` and a `DropDownList`

The value of the drop-down doesn't seem to get reflected in the Form values on submit.

Any ideas why?

Test Harness:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Field, Form, FormElement } from "@progress/kendo-react-form";
import { FormDropDownList } from "./FormDropDownList";

const handleSubmit1 = (dataItem) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(dataItem));
};

const AppComponent = () => {

  const moduleData = [
    {
        description: 'Alpha',
        module: 1
    },
    {
        description: 'Beta',
        module: 2
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit1}
     
      render={(formRenderProps) => (
        <FormElement>
          Name:
          <Field name="firstName" label="First name" 
          component="input" />

          <div className={"k-form-field-wrap"}>
                  <Field label={'Module'} 
                  name={'module'} 
                  id={'module'} 
                  required={true} 
                  dataItemKey={"module"} 
                  textField={"description"} 
                  data={moduleData} 
                  dropdownType={false} 
                  component={FormDropDownList} />
              </div>


          <button type={"submit"} disabled={false}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </FormElement>
      )}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<AppComponent />, document.querySelector("my-app"));
```

Custom component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { FieldWrapper } from "@progress/kendo-react-form";
import { Label, Error, Hint } from "@progress/kendo-react-labels";
import { DropDownList } from "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns";
import axios from "axios";

export const FormDropDownList = (fieldRenderProps) => {
  const {
    validationMessage,
    touched,
    label,
    id,
    valid,
    disabled,
    hint,
    wrapperStyle,
    dropdownType,
    data,
    value,
    name,
    style,
    ...others
  } = fieldRenderProps;
  const {
    onChange,
    dataItemKey,
    textField,
    extra_param,
    extra_param_name
  } = others;

  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = React.useState({});

  const loadDefaultData = (props) => {
    var cData = {};
    cData = props.find((obj) => obj[dataItemKey] === value);
    setCurrentValue(cData);
  };

  const onValueChange = (event) => {
    var cData = event.target.value; // selected data Object
    setCurrentValue(cData);
  };
 
  /**
   * Populate list
   */
  React.useEffect(() => {
 
      setState(data);
      loadDefaultData(data);
  
  }, []);

  const editorRef = React.useRef(null);
  const showValidationMessage = touched && validationMessage;
  const showHint = !showValidationMessage && hint;
  const hintId = showHint ? `${id}_hint` : "";
  const errorId = showValidationMessage ? `${id}_error` : "";
  const labelId = label ? `${id}_label` : "";
  return (
    <FieldWrapper style={wrapperStyle}>
      <Label
        id={labelId}
        editorRef={editorRef}
        editorId={id}
        editorValid={valid}
        editorDisabled={disabled}
      >
        {label}
      </Label>
      <DropDownList
        onChange={onValueChange}
        ariaLabelledBy={labelId}
        ariaDescribedBy={`${hintId} ${errorId}`}
        ref={editorRef}
        valid={valid}
        id={id}
        name={name}
        value={currentValue}
        disabled={disabled}
        data={state}
        dataItemKey={dataItemKey}
        textField={textField}
        style={style}
      />
      {showHint && <Hint id={hintId}>{hint}</Hint>}
      {showValidationMessage && <Error id={errorId}>{validationMessage}</Error>}
    </FieldWrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full code for the Form, including the state and onValueChange function?

Comment: @jyangca full code is in the sandbox I posted

Comment: The sandbox code is about button and onChange event. I think you posted wrong link.

Comment: @jyangca I've posted the full code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The value of the drop-down doesn't seem to get reflected in the Form values on submit.
> Any ideas why?

You are getting the `kendo-react-form onChange` method here:

```
  const {
    onChange,
    dataItemKey,
    textField,
    extra_param,
    extra_param_name
  } = others;
```

The `onChange` declared here ( = `others.onChange`) is the function that updates the value for the submit. However your are sending `onValueChange` to the `DropDownList`

```
<DropDownList
  onChange={onValueChange}
```

And the `onValueChange` function doesn't call the `onChange` method from the `kendo-react-form` anywhere (so the form values are not changing in any way, since you are only setting a local state. This is basically why value of the drop-down doesn't get reflected in the Form values on submit)

---

Potential fix

You shouldn't need any state in `FormDropDownList`, but rather just send the default props provided by the form to the dropdown. So something like:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { FieldWrapper } from "@progress/kendo-react-form";
import { Label, Error, Hint } from "@progress/kendo-react-labels";
import { DropDownList } from "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns";
import axios from "axios";

export const FormDropDownList = (fieldRenderProps) => {
  const {
    validationMessage,
    touched,
    label,
    hint,
    wrapperStyle,
    dropdownType,
    extra_param,
    extra_param_name
    ...others
  } = fieldRenderProps;

  const editorRef = React.useRef(null);
  const showValidationMessage = touched && validationMessage;
  const showHint = !showValidationMessage && hint;
  const hintId = showHint ? `${id}_hint` : "";
  const errorId = showValidationMessage ? `${id}_error` : "";
  const labelId = label ? `${id}_label` : "";
  return (
    <FieldWrapper style={wrapperStyle}>
      <Label
        id={labelId}
        editorRef={editorRef}
        editorId={id}
        editorValid={valid}
        editorDisabled={disabled}
      >
        {label}
      </Label>
      
      {/* the props that are not explicitly defined bellow 
      will be transmitted trough {...others} part (ex: value, data, etc.) */}
      <DropDownList
        ariaLabelledBy={labelId}
        ariaDescribedBy={`${hintId} ${errorId}`}
        ref={editorRef}
        {...others}
      />
      {showHint && <Hint id={hintId}>{hint}</Hint>}
      {showValidationMessage && <Error id={errorId}>{validationMessage}</Error>}
    </FieldWrapper>
  );
};
```

Please note the above example is for giving you a hint and it might need small adjustments (without a minimal reproducible example I was not able to fully test your code and therefore neither this one.)

However the option with {...others} should work. You can also check a reproducible example with `Kendo React DropDownList` and the `{...others}` approach [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-cherry-3qn46w?file=/src/App.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer provided by @Berci...

The custom component needs a way to translate between the Objects selectable in the DropDown list, and a 'primitive' Form parameter value, and this needs to be updated whenever the DropDown selection is changed.

The way to achieve this is to have a `callback` triggered in the DropDown change event handler:

```
const onValueChange = (event) => {
    var cData = event.target.value; // selected data Object
    setCurrentValue(cData);
    onFormValueChange(cData);
};


/* translate between dropdown Object value and Form parameter value */
const onFormValueChange = React.useCallback((item) => {
    // onChange callback expects argument with 'value' property
    onChange({
        value: item[dataItemKey]
    });
}, [onChange, value]);
```